# 2D array simple issue

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a simple issue but it's a little bit confusing for me so I'd appreciate any and all help provided :).

Basically, I want a 2D array, that will be 9 in length + 1 value.
So if I were to initialize it it'd be:

```
int[,] array = new int[8, 1];
```

My problem is I'm getting confused. I'm making a tic tac toe game, the first value will be the position. I will use an int to increment a value each time a turn is played. However, the second value I want to hold '0' or '1' or '2'. '0' will mean nobody has played here yet '1' will mean x has played here and '2' will mean o has played here.

When accessing the array ideally (although I cannot) I'd like to just specify array[m] but to access the array I'd need to input array[m,0] for example. I want the second value to hold a value, not a position to access the array if that makes sense.

If I can't do this with a 2D array does anyone have a suggestion of what to use?
If any more info is needed please let me know.

Comment: Use a dictionary instead? Or some other collection of key/value pairs?

Comment: there is no need to specify a dimension of length 1, don't you just want int[] array = new int[9]?

Comment: I'd say you either want an array of [3, 3] or, like Gallen said, a Dictionary, possibly with some kind of enum as the key. Either way, I'd use `bool?` or another enum as the value, since then you have only three states.

Answer (score 1):

As James Gaunt said:

```
     int[] array = new int[9];
```

In this array the index is the position and the value stored at that index is what is there 0=Nothing,1= O's,2 = X's.

Your initial board state will look like

```
{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
```

Now X to move in the middle say:

```
// {0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0}
array[4] = 2;
```

Now O to move in the right middle:

```
// {0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0}
array[5] = 1;
```

Etc.. until a win state is reached or no more 0's exist on the board.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a 2D array of objects where each object holds the value of the space and another for the position (Im guessing you mean the order that it gets played).

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
IDictionary<int, int> ticTacToeBoard = new Dictionary<int, int>();

//initialize and reset all values on the board to 0
ticTacToeBoard = resetBoard(ticTacToeBoard);

int position = 1;
int value = ticTacToeBoard[position];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're after a 3x3 grid, you can simply use a 2D array for this:

```
const int width = 3;
const int height = 3;

var board = new int[height, width];
```

You could then expand it to check to see if all values are 0 (e.g. the board is empty) using something like:

```
bool AllEmpty(int[,] board, int width, int height)
{
  for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
  {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x)
    {
      if (board[y, x] != 0)
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

(You could probably do something nicer using LINQ, but LINQ and multiple dimensions doesn't play too nice, so I've kept it simple for now).

This is essentially representing this:

```
000 
000 
000
```

You'll need to do some initialisation and modifying values for this to work.